# I have a question on the definition of 'good' primes in the paper of Cohen and Martinet

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, computational-number-theory, heuristics

I'm reading the paper of Cohen and Martinet 'Etude heuristique des groups de classes'.

In the section 6, for an central idempotent $e$ of $\mathbb{Q}[\Gamma]$ and a prime $p$, the 'goodness' of $p$ is defined.

The second condition says for each irreducible component $e'$ of $e$, $e'\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}[\Gamma]$ is a maximal $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$-order of $\mathbb{Q}[\Gamma]$.

But the $\mathbb{Q}$-dimension of $\mathbb{Q}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}}e'\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}[\Gamma]$ is always strictly less than $|\Gamma|$. Thus the second condition does not make sense to me.

Does the second condition actually mean that $e'\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}[\Gamma]$ is a maximal order in $e'\mathbb{Q}[\Gamma]$?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I just asked Martinet, and although he says it is very old in his memory he believes the answer is yes, and this sentence should have been rephrased.

Comment: @HenriCohen Thank you very much for the clarification!